# Topology, atlas, smooth manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $X$ be a set, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $((U_i,\phi_i))_i$ a family of subsets $U_i\subseteq X$ with injective functions $\phi_i: U_i\to\mathbb{R}^n$, which hold the following conditions:
>
> 1. $\bigcup_{i} U_i=X$
> 2. for every $i$ is $\phi_i(U_i)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open
> 3. for all $i,j$ is $\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open and $\phi_j\circ\phi^{-1}_i:\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth.

---

> 1. Show, that $X$ has exactly one topology, in regards to the family $((U_i,\phi_i))_i$ is an atlas.
> 2. Conclude: Is the family $(U_i.\phi_i)_i$ countable, then is $X$ with this atlas a smooth manifold.

Hello,

I Have a question to this task.
How can I characterize the open subsets of $X$ with $(U_i,\phi_i)$ conveniently?

To get an atlas, it needs to be $\bigcup_{(V_i,\psi_i)} V_i=X$ with charts $(V_i,\psi_i)$.

The problem is, that $(U_i,\phi_i)$ are not charts, since $\phi_i$ is not a homeomorphism.

So I need a topology, such that $\phi_i$ is a homeomorphism, or not?
How can I give such a topology?

Thanks in advance for your hints and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Since the functions $\phi_i$ are injective and the images of the $U_i$ are open you can let $\phi^{-1}(U_i)$ be a basis for the topology on X. The maps are now automatically homeomorphisms and you can check that this does indeed define a topology on X.

Comment: Ok. So I observe to topology which is induced by $\mathcal{B}:=\{\phi_i^{-1}(U_i)|i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I have to show, that this is a topology. Therefore includes $\emptyset, X$, the union of sets and countable cut of sets. I am not sure, how to start...

Comment: Well, it doesn't directly include all of that. We declare them to be a basis of the topology. The actual topology will contain all of those things.

Comment: Yes, sure. So we declare $\mathcal{B}$ as the base. Therefore every open set has to be representable as union of sets which are in $\mathcal{B}$. Now I have to show, that I can represent $\emptyset$ and $X$ like that. $\emptyset$ is clear, since you can just take the "empty" union. How can I represent $X$?

Comment: I think it's rather taking $\{U_i\}$ as a subbase, unless the altlas under consideration is maximal.

Comment: Property 1 in your original post shows that X is a union of these sets.

Comment: You cannot that the primages of the U_i as a basis: you need to takr the preimages of **all** open subsets of the U_i. Otherwise the topology is not even T_1 in general (this happens, for example, if there is only one $i$)

Comment: This construction is just a special case of an initial topology. I don't think it is possible to conclude that the topology that these maps induce is Hausdorff. One can take an atlas of any non-Hausdorff manifold as an example, it satifies all the conditions and the induced topology is the same as the topology on the manifold.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos: Yes, we were told, that this will not be Hausdorff in general.

Comment: @MichaelMenke: Why is $\phi_i^{-1}(U_i)=U_i$, to conclude it by property 1?